# Expanding DIV slides behind DIV beneath it

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm not sure that I'm going to get an answer here, as I'd need to post a lot of CSS and html to get a working recreation, however...

I have structure something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Test A</legend> 
    <h3>Test A</h3>   
    <p>
        Something here.
    </p>
    <div style="display:hidden;">I'm dynamically displayed</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Test B</legend> 
    <h3>Test B</h3>   
    <p>
        Something B here.
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

I have code that toggles the display of my hidden div using jQuery and .show().  This works fine in IE8, firefox and Safari, but when I stick IE8 into compatibility mode, then the first fieldset (Test A) will expand, but the expansion happens behind the second fieldset, which doesn't move (i.e. it slides down behind it).

I have quite a bit of CSS in use here, and I'm going to have to go back and unpick the whold lot, which isn't a fun idea.  If anybody has any idea of one of the IE7 rendering issues that might be affecting this, then I'd very much appreciate it. (note that there is more to the content in these fieldsets than shown, including floated divs).

---

Quick note - if I stick IE7 into quirks mode, it works (but wrecks the rest of my layout) - in standards mode, I get the above behaviour.

Comment: Are you using `z-index`?

Comment: You might consider throwing up a small sample page on one of your sites that exhibits the problem. There are a lot of things that html developers will want to see such as your doctype, actual javascript code, etc...  Also, recreating the problem in a small setting will help you go through the motions of understanding exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Christ Lively - In the process of cutting a page down now, however there is a lot of code there and I'm not at liberty to just put it up on the world wild web, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - I don't make use of z-index in my styling, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this was a combination of various position:relative and position:static layout items (somewhat bodged in from earlier).  When my fieldsets were positioned relatively, then they weren't shifting (due to other styled elements around them).

Position:static seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved this issue on my site. A float: left and position:relative did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

check your z-index and that overflow:hidden is in the fieldset style